# Efficiency of Array with individual mutexes protecting them or one mutex protecting it

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mingw

So I was a doing a bit of thinking the other day about concurrency and I was wondering whether it was faster to protect an array with individual mutexes for each element or whether it was faster for the entire array to use one mutex to protect all the data in it. Logically, I figured that a program would execute faster with invidual mutexes so that each thread would only need to "checkout" the element they need, which kinda sounds like it would allow for better concurrency. If only one was able to execute at a time waiting on the mutex, then surely there would be a lot of waiting going on. To test this theory, I created a set of tests like [this](http://pastebin.com/wAm6HjCY). In both functions, all that was done is that a mutex is locked and a random value is written to a random location in the array, the only difference being that each element has it's own mutex in the first function, and then all elements share a mutex in the second. I left the number of runs a constant 25 to get a good average at the end of each test.

I ran it with:
NUM_ELEMENTS = 10;
NUM_THREADS = 5;
[results](http://pastebin.com/Qd3Tmqpa)

NUM_ELEMENTS = 100;
NUM_THREADS = 5;
[results](http://pastebin.com/AFpaanX2)

NUM_ELEMENTS = 10;
NUM_THREADS = 10;
[results](http://pastebin.com/wgA90ZC9)

NUM_ELEMENTS = 100;
NUM_THREADS = 10;
[results](http://pastebin.com/HVeE2eMD)

NUM_ELEMENTS = 10;
NUM_THREADS = 15;
[results](http://pastebin.com/iAqrfndW)

NUM_ELEMENTS = 100;
NUM_THREADS = 15;
[results](http://pastebin.com/FbVJFJwh)

For the set that use 10 elements in the array, here is a graph of the averages for the 2 different methods.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WdyJ.png)

For the set that use 100 elements in the array, here is a graph of the averages for the 2 different methods.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJotc.png)

For the record this was all done in MingW as i don't have a working linux box ( because reasons), with no other flags besides -c++11. As you can see, my original theory, was entirely incorrect. Apparently if an entire array of values shares one mutex for writing, it is quite a bit faster than each value having it's own lock. This seems entirely counter intuitive. So my question to you clever people out there, what is going on in the system or elsewhere that is causing this conundrum. Please correct my thinking!

EDIT: just noticed the graphs didn't import correctly, so ya'll have no idea what is going on. Fixed

EDIT: On the suggestion of @nanda, I implemented 2 more similar tests, except utilizing a thread pool of 4 threads, that process the same number of random assignments to the test vector as the other threads make. [Here](http://pastebin.com/jgzmRbZh) is the updated tests, and [here](http://pastebin.com/1PhwNc5q) is the output file.On a whimsey, i also decreased the number of threads the original 2 test used to 4 (the number of cores on my cpu), and as the output suggests, the two methods are now very very similar in average time elapsed. This allows for the conclusion that @nanda's reasoning is correct, that a large number of runnable threads, (or just more threads than you have cores), causes the system to have to queue up process threads which causes a large amount of delay. But also on a whim, i added a "control" group so to speak which was just an asynchronous loops that makes the same number of random accesses randomely to the array. It was considerably faster than the concurrent methods of doing so. Also, as you may notice, the threadpool method performaing the same amount of accesses as the original two methods, complete much quicker than the original 2 methods.

So here are my 2 new questions. Why in the world are the concurrent methods so incredibly slow as compared to the asynchronous method. Also, why is the threadpool method of concurrency quite a bit faster than my original method?

Comment: From your results: As the the number of threads increase the time taken by individual lock case to complete increased multi-fold - this indicates that the operating system scheduler is overwhelmed by the number of run-able threads (as there is no contention for lock) and end up with a big processor queue length - ending up with total  latency = queue length * individual work item latency. Checking the processor queue length performance counters would give a clue.

Comment: now that's interesting. I never thought that a wealth of runnable threads could be considered a bad thing. Do you happen to know of a tool to check the processor queue? (This is somewhat new to me)

Comment: Another thought, should this be true, that the number of runnable threads is overwhelming, if applied the same concepts of a shared mutex or individual mutices, but utilizing a thread pool that limits the number of threads to say, the number of cores on my cpu, do you think that I would be seeing different results, just posting functions to an event queue of some sort?

Comment: Yeah, using a thread pool to limit the threads to number of cores would be a good way to test the conjecture and the right way to get more work done in short time if contentions have been nullified - like  in your case using individual locks. But also other bottle necks might show up - like high random access to memory -  referring to the different locks - if not fitting in cache causing delays.

Comment: I suppose your non-concurrent control test is not using any mutex there by not wasting time doing two system calls each iteration - but still a 50x speed compared to thread pool based concurrency cannot be explained by just the system calls. Also the individual lock case is not gaining much parallelism compared to the shared lock - may be there is contention for other resource. Thread pool limited by number of core is better because if 4 runnable threads on 4 cores finished in time T - 8 runnable threads on 4 cores would need more than 2T because of the scheduler takes more time.

Comment: In addition to the task switching overhead mentioned in other comments, it's likely that you're experiencing [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)

Comment: @nanda - when you say a contention for other resources, is there anything within the scope of my program i can do to avoid that, or will that be entirely dictated by the system?

Comment: @JimMischel - Okay, i read that article and another couple related, and i can see how that can cause cache misses, but can false sharing truly account for a 50x increase in time? It still seems a little extravagant.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis - another way of looking at the fact that individual lock case is taking up the same time as the shared lock and not giving the parallelism that is sought would be to assume that it is the system calls that is causing the latency and verify that by using a single threaded loop with and without lock (I am hoping the lock would act in a full fledged manner even in the absence of contention - may be it would help to show some contention initially to lock and go single threaded for the sake of measurement )

Comment: I had false sharing cost me almost 25x. See http://blog.mischel.com/2011/12/29/more-about-cache-contention/ for the details.

Comment: A more analytic view of the comment I made above. We could equate (total latency = contention count * contention cost + other cost) and in you individual lock case you reduced the contention count by a factor of 10 - despite that the total latency was pegged at the same value - so the contention cost is too small and nullifies the 1/10 factor while "other cost" is what shows up in both the case - which I believe is the lock/unlock call cost.